# Laravel - accessor doesn't work when collection returned as JSON

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an API with Laravel for VueJS frontend SPA.

I need to accept and return dates as 'd-m-Y', not as 'Y-m-d' as it's stored in DB.
Data mutator is working ok and I managed to save it properly with given date,
but when I run:

```
$active = Announcement::where('group_id', $this->user->group_id)->where('dateTo', '>=', Carbon::today())->get();
        return response()->json($active);
```

I am getting pure DB data, instead of getting it formatted.
For example I have `dateTo` field which needs to be formatted :

```
 public function getDateToAttribute($value)
    {
        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value);
        return $date->format('d-m-Y');
    }
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Jared said, accessors/mutators only exist when called by your application. So, in collection returned as JSON, no accessor/mutator exist.
Make a loop to call all your needed accessor/mutator is waaay too fat, but Laravel come with a built-in solution

In your model `Announcement.php`, you just have to specifies the accessors/mutators that will always be appended on your requests.

```
protected $appends = array('dateTo');
```

With this solution, each request will contain a dateTo parameter, formated as you like.

greets !

**PS :** You can make the `$appends` array change depending on your request, so all your request returning JSON will send the `dateTo` parameters, but the other won't.

Comment: Awesome ;) this solves the issue for eager loading in JSON without looping.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel will run the accessors when you convert the model to an array or json.

So I would update your code to:

```
$active = Announcement::where('group_id', $this->user->group_id)->where('dateTo', '>=', Carbon::today())->get();

return response()->json($active->toArray());
```

Comment: it's not working... still not going through accessor... It should do this thing without ->toArray because it's converting to JSON...

Comment: Yeah that is true.
Looking at this more closely, looks like your date field is `dateTo` not `date_to`. Laravel is only going to do the automatic accessor if your field name matches the format it expects, i.e. `date_to`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    $active = Announcement::where('group_id', $this->user->group_id)->where('dateTo', '>=', Carbon::today())->get();
    foreach($active as $activeRecords){
       print_r($activeRecords->dateTo);
    }
```

Attribute

```
public function getDateToAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
}
```