# Laravel 10.x Collection : SOME model's attributes kept encrypted whereas others are correctly decrypted

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am upgrading my website from Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 10.x.

I have a Model User that has the following attributes "normalEmail" and "normalTel" which are encrypted and have a their own accessors (because of camel case column names in database instead of snake case) :

```
    public function getNormalEmailAttribute($value)
    {
        // Access the encrypted value directly from $attributes
        $encryptedValue = $this->attributes['normalEmail'];

        $text = self::$UNAVAILABLE;
        try {
            $text = Crypt::decrypt($encryptedValue, true);
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            Log::warning("message");
            ("Error while decrypting normal email " . $encryptedValue . " : " . $e->getMessage());
        }

        Log::info("EMail (returned value) is " . $text);

        return $text;
    }

    public function getNormalTelAttribute($value)
    {
        // Access the encrypted value directly from $attributes
        $encryptedValue = $this->attributes['normalTel'];


        $text = self::$UNAVAILABLE;
        try {
            $text = Crypt::decrypt($encryptedValue, true);
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            Log::warning("Error while decrypting normal tel " . $encryptedValue . " : " . $e->getMessage());
        }

        return $text;
    }
```

In my Controller when I loop through the collection of Users like this I can see the emails and phone numbers :

```
// Using &$user because I am changing some attributes (colors)
        foreach ($users as &$user) {
            Log::info("User has email : " . $user->normalEmail . 'and phone ' . $user->normalTel);

}
```

But then just after the loop when I check the whole $users collection before it is returned to the view the normalEmail value is encrypted (NOT the normalTel one which is well decrypted and which behaviour bugs me) :

```
        Log::info("Returned users collection is " . $users);
```

I tried to convert it to array and back to collection with the same effect of normalEmail being encrypted.

I also tried the map function which shows decrypted normalEmail field inside, but after it the normalEmail field is still encrypted in the collection :

```
$users->map(function ($user) { 
 
    Log::info("The email in the map is " . $user->normalEmail); // shown decrypted

    return $user;
 });

 Log::info("Returned users collection is " . $users); //normalEmail field shown encrypted
```

So it looks like my accessor for normalEmail is not called when the Collection is returned but is when looping through each element of it.

Please note : in Laravel 5.2 both attributes were returned decrypted.

One solution I haven't tried so far but am thinking about right while writing this question is to generate a new collection with decrypted values and return it. But there may be something better to do.

EDIT :
I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082466/laravel-accessor-doesnt-work-when-collection-returned-as-json) and added the $appends property in my Model like this and it works :

```
protected $appends = [
        'normalEmail',
    ];
```

Still I don't know why it is required for normalEmail field and not for normalTel field (although they are both stored in a "Text" column). Moreover if I add "normalTel" to the $appends array then the field normalTel is decrypted twice which does not work (see DecryptException).

What's going on actually and how can I get both fields decrypted when the whole collection is returned without recreating a new collection only with decrypted values ?

Any help appreciated :-)

Kind regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - accessor doesn't work when collection returned as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082466/laravel-accessor-doesnt-work-when-collection-returned-as-json)

Comment: Yeah @OMiShah that's what I also found after writing this question (see my Edit). But I don't understand why only this field has to be appended whereas the other ones do not have to. If you write the explanation in an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: that's weird tbh if one is working fine. Can you add code showing how you're fetching the data, controller code?

Comment: BTW, you're accessing phone number on the $RDV (`$RDV->patientTel`) not the $user? From where does $RDV comes?

Comment: @OMiShah Thanks for pointing that out, this was a typo (on stackoverflow not in the actual code). I wrote an answer that explains what I was doing. Actually in the loop I was modifying (formatting) the normalTel whereas I was doing nothing to normalEmail (only printing it). So that's why the behaviour was different. Now that I modify both of them in the loop they are both returned decrypted even though there are not in the model's $appends array.

Comment: @OMiShah Now what I described yesterday does not hold true anymore! Even though I am modifying the collection attributes in the loop, I have to add those attributes to the $appends array. Otherwise they are shown encrypted. Maybe I missed that due to caching. Let's see if this works now reliably!

Comment: that's why I said 'it's weird' yesterday and that's how $appends work, if you need to expose / add a modified field in a response, you have to add to the $appends. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there was a subtle typo in the setter name (one "t" added). Bottom line is use the $appends array as suggested by others (and carefully check for typos if this does not work with $appends)!